# How do I pass a struct by reference in WinRT Component C++/CX

Tags: struct, components, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have the following in my WinRT component:

```
public value struct WinRTStruct
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

public ref class WinRTComponent sealed
{
    public:
    WinRTComponent();
    int TestPointerParam(WinRTStruct * wintRTStruct);
};

int WinRTComponent::TestPointerParam(WinRTStruct * wintRTStruct)
{
    wintRTStruct->y = wintRTStruct->y + 100;
    return wintRTStruct->x;
}
```

But, it seems that the value of winRTStruct->y and x are always 0 inside the method, when called from C#:

```
WinRTComponent comp = new WinRTComponent();
WinRTStruct winRTStruct;
winRTStruct.x = 100;
winRTStruct.y = 200;
comp.TestPointerParam(out winRTStruct);
textBlock8.Text = winRTStruct.y.ToString();
```

What is the correct way to pass a struct by reference so it an be updated inside the method of a WinRTComponent written in C++/CX?

Comment: I'm not sure how does passing by reference work in WinRT, but in C#, if you pass a parameter using `out`, the original value is not used, you need `ref` for that.

Comment: @svick I'm a bit late here, but thought I'd add that you can choose between using `ref` or the `&` symbol ( example:  `comp.TestPointerParam(&winRTStruct)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699870.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a struct by reference.  All value types (including structs) in winrt are passed by value.  Winrt structs are expected to be relatively small - they're intended to be used for holding things like Point and Rect.

In your case, you've indicated that the struct is an "out" parameter - an "out" parameter is write-only, its contents are ignored on input and are copied out on return.  If you want a structure to be in and out, split it into two parameters - one "in" parameter and another "out" parameter (in/out parameters are not allowed in WinRT because they don't project to JS the way you expect them to project).

Answer (score 1):

My co-worker helped me solve this.
In WinRT components, it seems that the best way to do this is to define a ref struct instead of a value struct:

```
public ref struct WinRTStruct2 sealed
{
private: int _x;
public:
 property int X
 {
    int get(){ return _x; }
    void set(int value){ _x = value; }
 }
private: int _y;
public:
 property int Y
 {
    int get(){ return _y; }
    void set(int value){ _y = value; }
 }
};
```

But this creates other problems.  Now the VS11 compiler gives INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR when I try to add a method to the ref struct that returns an instance of the struct.